# Question about the martingale property of stochastic integral

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $W_{t}$ be a Wiener process, and let
$$X_{t} = \int^{t}_{0}W_{\tau}d\tau$$
Is $X_{t}$ a martingale? We can rewrite in differential form as
$$dX_{t} = W_{t}dt$$
,which means $X_{t}$ is a diffusion process with only drift part $W_{t}$ and therefore $X_{t}$ is not a martingale. 
However, by integration by parts, we have
\begin{align}
X_{t} &= t W_{t} - \int^{t}_{0}\tau dW_{\tau}\\
&=t \int^{t}_{0}dW_{\tau} - \int^{t}_{0}\tau dW_{\tau}\\
&= \int^{t}_{0}(t-\tau)dW_{\tau}
\end{align}
$t-\tau$ is a deterministic, square integrable function, according to the martingale property of stochastic integral, $X_{t}$ is a martingale.
Now my question is which analysis above is the right one? Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $X_t$ is square integrable, then the integral
\begin{align*}
\int_0^t X_{\tau} dW_{\tau}
\end{align*}
is a martingale. Here, the integrand $X_{\tau}$ does not depend on the integral limit $t$. However, in your case, the integrand, $t-\tau$, depends on $t$, then the condition for the martingality of the integral fails.

Comment: Thank you very much! However, when it comes to the distribution of $X_{t}$, it is usual to use the theorem: if $f(t)$ is a deterministic square integrable function, then the stochastic integral $\int ^{t}_{0}f(\tau)dW_{\tau}$ is a normal random variable of mean 0 and variance $\int ^{t} _{0} |f(\tau)|^{2}d\tau$. Therefore, $X_{t} \sim N(0, \int ^{t}_{0}(t-\tau)^{2}d\tau)$. That is to say, $t-\tau$ should be a deterministic square integrable function, which is also the condition for the martingality. How to explain the distribution of $X_{t}$?

Comment: @cmd1991: The distribution of $\int_0^t(t-\tau)dW_{\tau}$ is normal, as the limit in $L^2$ or in probability of normal random variables is normal. Though the martingality condition fails, however, Ito's isometry formula still holds. That is, your distribution is fine.

Comment: How does the martingality fail?  It looks square integrable to me...

Comment: @user9403: Martingality requires that the integrand is independent of the integral limit.

Comment: If we define the martingale as always having an upper limit which is equal to the integrand I agree.  However the equation in question can be interpreted as $\int_0^s (t-\tau) dW_{\tau}$ in which case the process is a martingale for $0 \leq s \leq t$.  However, the process $\int_0^ tW_{\tau} d\tau$ can never be a martingale, which I think gets to the heart of cmd1991's question.

Comment: @user9403: Thank you but I am confused with the words" we define the martingale as always having an upper limit which is equal to the integrand" .

Comment: @Gordon: Do you mean that $t-\tau$ is square integrable in $[0,t]$ but does not meet the condition because the integrand is dependent of the integral limit? Actually I cannot find a theorem describing the condition, can you provide a link? Thank you.

Comment: @cmd1991 If $X_t=\int_0 ^ t (t-\tau)dW_{\tau}$ and $X_s=\int_0^s (s-\tau)dW_\tau$ then I agree completely with Gordon.  My interpretation of your question was that $X_s=\int_0^s (t-\tau) dW_\tau $ in which case $X_s$ is a martingale.

Comment: @cmd1991: Any stochastic calculus book has a discussion of the martingale property for $\int_0^tX_{\tau}dW_{\tau}$. However, you will not find any martingale property for $\int_0^t X(\tau, t)dW_{\tau}$. See, for example, the book by Karatzas and Shreve: http://www.amazon.com/Brownian-Stochastic-Calculus-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387976558.

Answer (score 1):

The two processes are not pathwise equal.  Here is a simulation (sample path) of the two processes $(t-\tau)dW_{\tau}$ and $W_\tau d\tau$: [image: Martingale and BM Average]

Note that both processes have the same value at the final time.

Comment: What are the two processes? Do you mean the $(t-\tau)dW_{\tau}$ and $W_{\tau}d\tau$?

Comment: Yes, I've edited my answer to clarify.

Comment: @cmd1991: $(t-\tau)dW_{\tau}$ and $W_{\tau}d\tau$ are not processes. They are some incremental changes.